# Zed tool and the accuracy

Tags: zap

I setup the Zap tool as a proxy, and captured browser traces of the site (Urls). I ran the tool, and produced a report. In the report, I picked few input elements on a given pages that was flagged by the report and but I couldn't get any success with reflecting the value, thus Xss. I am aware about the false positives etc. but I am puzzled because I thought the tool would be able to accurately find Xss issues. If the pentesters found Xss issues that are genuine so why can't this tool do the same or how else did they do it? am I missing something here?

Comment: Soooooo many details overlooked. Do you have the alpha and beta scan rules installed? Did you run an active scan? Why do you believe the inputs you selected are subject to XSS? If you can produce reliable false negatives I'm sure the team would be interested in your specific test examples.

Answer (score 1):

No tool is free from false positives, whatever their marketing might say ;)
Tools have to have to balance false positives vs false negatives and the number of requests they make, and hence the time they take. At tool that is 100% accurate but takes months to scan a site is no use to anyone.
Its not possible for us to know if the issues are false positives or not without a lot more details.
Skilled manual pentesters will always be better than any one tool, but they are not cheep. Automated tools like ZAP can find potential issues much earlier in the development lifecycle. But if you have a high value site you should really be paying for manual pentinsting in addition to using automated tools.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, KingThorin and Simon
I used forced user scenario and zap proxy. I spidered  all in scope and ran active scan all in scope. Url:http://xxxxx.com/sites/lookup.aspx?id=1111&field=%3Balert%281%29&fieldx
Yet  when I tried this with the url with above payload but value got reflected but not as code ie didn’t execute? 

Unsure about the alpha/beta rules applied or not? changed policy for xss only.  Simon yes agree no tool can be 100% accurate. Any better approach to a better xss findings with Z tool please. All help, appreciated. Also any resource please.

Comment: Maybe I‘ve confused you guys and sorry if I have. I would like to improve my usage of zen tool for xss. It seems u need to get more input rules. Xss Dom rules I have heard mentioned elsewhere.
What else is there in the market that is a help in input rules? 
Maybe I need to improve how to analyse the report. Any ideas of where I can specialise at xss with zap tool. I know Simon does few vids and they are great and much appreciated. Anything else?

Comment: You could use the actual fuzzer with various XSS payload lists.